# AJAX/PHP/JS readyState = 1 and Status = 0 ALWAYS. No response text

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I've been trying lately to use this sample of AJAX to compare form data to an SQL database from one http://www.example.com domain.  My issue is that the readyState is always 1 and my Status is always 0.  It is expecting 4 and 200 respectively.  It also always returns responseText=""  I've looked all over StackOverflow but have unsuccessfully found anything helpful.

I've boggled my mind over what could be the issue, but I just can't seem to get it to work.

*I've also tried to set file permissions on both the JS and PHP, but it functions the same.

*I'm using a dedicated web server to host all this, and I have no problem running most scripts.

**//HTML** GenerateRep.html

Excuse the lack of < and > tags missing, the code won't appear without them.

```
form id="formgen" onsubmit="GenRep(this)"
....form stuff....
button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button
```

**//JAVASCRIPT** GenerateRep.js

```
function GenRep(formgen) {

var email = formgen['repemail'];
var hash = formgen['reppass'];
var first = formgen['firstname'];
var last = formgen['lastname'];
var territory = formgen['territory'];

hash.value = CryptoJS.SHA256(hash.value);

var login = email + ";" + hash.value + ";" + first + ";" + last + ";" + territory;

Login(login);


}

function Login(login) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                if(xhttp.responseText == "VALID") {
                    window.location.href = "success.html";
                } else if (xhttp.responseText == "INVALID") {
                    $("#login_error").text("Failed! Plese check your info.");
                } else {
                    window.location.href = "error.php";
                }
            }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "Validate.php?q=" + login, true);
xhttp.send();
}
```

**//PHP** Validate.php

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
include ("ConnectDB.php");

// Check connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {

die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);

} 

//THIS IS A TEST TO SEE IF reponseText FUNCTIONS. IT DOES NOT. 
//echo "testecho";


$whole = $_REQUEST['q'];

$userPass = explode (";", $whole);


$sql1 = "SELECT UName FROM Reps WHERE UName = '$userPass[0]'";
$result = $conn->query($sql1);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
$conn->close();
echo "INVALID";

} else {

$sql = "INSERT INTO Reps (UName, Pass, FName, LName, Territory) VALUES ('$userPass[0]', '$userPass[1]', '$userPass[2]', '$userPass[3]', $userPass[4])";

if ($conn->query($sql) === FALSE) {
$conn->close();
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;

}


$conn->close();
echo "VALID";

}
?>
```

Comment: if you paste into the browser the GET request http://yoursite.com/Validate.php?q=data the script run fine?

Comment: Are you sure the PHP is running and returning a response?  The reason I ask is because your readyState is not changing and that is usually indicative of the no communication back from the server.

Comment: @Thesee - Yes, I was able to get it to run no problem. It completes what it needs to do and returns valid.

Comment: @AndrewSteitz - As far as I can tell it runs.  I've gone to the URL directly and had the PHP work. This is on a webserver too with a bunch of other PHP utilities working.  I believe some of them even utilize AJAX, so this is strange to me.

Comment: @MorganJ - a better way to check if there is actual communication going on between browser and server is to open the dev tools in your browser (usually by pressing F12) and then navigating to the tab titled "Network".Clear the tab and then click on whatever is supposed to trigger the xhttp call.  Watch to see if your script actually initiates a call to the server and then see if the server ever responds.

Comment: @AndrewSteitz - I did what you suggested and sure enough, Validate.php is not running.  I've pulled down the files to a local server to see if maybe it was a firewall issue, but I am still getting the same status code.  I have a friend who is running some AJAX (we work in the same office) that seems to be executing correctly, but when you step down in the JS, it shows that it's also throwing a state of 1 and status of 0. At this point I have no idea what could be causing the error, perhaps there is another way to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

What could cause the PHP to not fire?

Comment: I think I've got it now, I switched to JQuery and prevent the form submit event, this lets the page wait for the request.  What was happening before, I think, was that the form was submitting and bringing me to a null page, then firing the JS from there.  But since it was Null, and not directly defined, it wouldn't work; and since it would then be on another domain, the call wouldn't reach the PHP.  That's my guess anywho.

Comment: @MorganJ would you mind giving me "credit" by "Accepting" my answer below? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I previously "commented" instead of creating an "Answer" because I wasn't suggesting a fix, just a debug step to make sure what you thought was happening, was actually happening.

Since my suggestion helped you figure out the problem, I created this "Answer" in case you want to give me "credit". :-)